# What are the equivalent band combinations in Sentinel-2?

Tags: arcmap, sentinel-2, band

The following is the band combination of RGB to represent in natural colour, vegetation analysis, infrared colour for Landsat-8: -

- Natural Colour:- 4 3 2
- Colour Infrared (vegetation):- 5 4 3
- Healthy Vegetation:- 5 6 2
- Land/Water:- 5 6 4
- Vegetation Analysis:- 6 5 4

I need to know the band combination to use in Sentinel-2 to represent the image in natural colour combination, infrared, vegetation analysis. What are the band combination for this and what band need to be added in composite bands (data management tool) in ArcGIS??

Answer (score 1):

I think minimal search effort could have answered this question.
But you can compare it e.g. from these 2 Tables - just look up the closest wave-lenght that matches Landsat 8 in the Sentinel 2 Table:

There may be different conventions on how things are displayed (e.g. using B8 or B8A in S2 when calculating NDVI etc.) this differs from sensor to sensor.

For specific indices, the [Index Data Base](https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/is.php?sensor_id=96) is a *fantastic* resource, maybe it's worth checking this out, too.

**Landsat 8**

[image]
[image]

**Sentinel 2**

[image]

*Sources*:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_8
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-2